# Access root variable from object in Adobe Animate

Tags: html, variables, jquery-animate, movieclip

In Adobe Animate, using the HTML5 canvas, I've created a boolean variable at the root level called var_grandparents. I've now created a movie clip. When the movie clip gets to a certain frame, it's supposed to reference the variable and, if the variable is true, start another movie clip playing, but I can't get it to see it. I just keep getting 'undefined'.

I've tried `alert(this.parent.var_grandparents)` and `alert(Object.var_grandparents)`, but I just get 'undefined'. Is there a way to reference it, please?